# Passing parameters to Ajax request in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have this function:

```
function tagsInputFabricantes(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var fabricante_distribuidor_id = data.ent.id,
        producto_solicitud_id = data.ent.idProductoSolicitud,
        fabricante_producto_solicitud_id = data.ent.idFabricanteProductoSolicitud;

    $('#tagsInputFab-' + data.ent.idFabricanteProductoSolicitud).select2({
        placeholder: 'Seleccione uno o más países',
        closeOnSelect: false,
        multiple: true,
        width: '100%',
        ajax: {
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: true,
            quietMillis: 2000, // waits 2 seconds before triggers the search
            url: function () {
                return Routing.generate('obtenerPaisesNoAgregadosFabricante');
            },
            data: function (pais, fabricante_distribuidor_id, producto_solicitud_id, fabricante_producto_solicitud_id) {
                return {
                    filtro: pais,
                    fabricante_distribuidor_id: fabricante_distribuidor_id,
                    producto_solicitud_id: producto_solicitud_id,
                    fabricante_producto_solicitud_id: fabricante_producto_solicitud_id
                }
            },
            results: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data.entities
                };
            }
        },
        formatAjaxError: function () {
            return Translator.trans('mensajes.msgNoConexionServidor', {}, 'AppBundle');
        }
    });
}
```

And I need to pass three extra parameters to the Ajax query to be sent via REQUEST and this is how I'm doing:

```
    console.log(data); // watch wath is getting in this object

    // Gets the values and assign to vars
    var fabricante_distribuidor_id = data.ent.id,
        producto_solicitud_id = data.ent.idProductoSolicitud,
        fabricante_producto_solicitud_id = data.ent.idFabricanteProductoSolicitud;

     ....
     // Pass needed parameters as extra parameters for data 
     data: function (pais, fabricante_distribuidor_id, producto_solicitud_id, fabricante_producto_solicitud_id) {
                return {
                    filtro: pais,
                    fabricante_distribuidor_id: fabricante_distribuidor_id,
                    producto_solicitud_id: producto_solicitud_id,
                    fabricante_producto_solicitud_id: fabricante_producto_solicitud_id
                }
      }
```

But it's not working since the URL contains only this: `url&filtro=&fabricante_distribuidor_id=1&producto_solicitud_id=&fabricante_producto_solicitud_id=` and that is wrong. The `console.log()` logs this to console:

```
Object {success: true, ent: Object}
     ent: Object
         id: 1
         idFabricanteProductoSolicitud: 18
         idProductoSolicitud: 18
         nombre: "Dist1"
         pais: ""
     __proto__: ...
```

Where is the error? Why parameters aren't passed to the `data` function? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: add a parameter to the ajax: `dataType: 'script'`

Comment: @surajck why should I change from `json` to `script`? What is the purpose of that change?

Comment: I don't know why your `data` attribute is a function. Its either plain text, JSON,XML etc. Not a function. Create the JSON outside the ajax call and give that as `data`

Comment: @surajck it's a JSON notice the brackets `{ ... }`

Comment: I missed that! sorry!

Comment: @surajck it seems you aren't familiar with the plugin. Why are you saying `data` shouldn't be function when the docs clearly show it is

Comment: You're right. I figured that while looking through the docs now.

Comment: For those looking on, this is definitely Select2 3.5.2, not the 4.0 beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are defining the query parameters that need to be sent as function parameters. Because nothing is being passed in through the function parameters, the variables are being set to `false` instead of taking on the value that was set globally.

```
data: function (pais, fabricante_distribuidor_id, producto_solicitud_id, fabricante_producto_solicitud_id) {
    // parameters 2, 3, and 4 are `undefined`

    return {
        filtro: pais,
        fabricante_distribuidor_id: fabricante_distribuidor_id,
        producto_solicitud_id: producto_solicitud_id,
        fabricante_producto_solicitud_id: fabricante_producto_solicitud_id
    }
}
```

Now, if you remove these parameters, they should take on the value of the next scope. This is where you are setting them from the incoming data, which is what it looks like you were aiming to do.

```
data: function (pais) {
    return {
        filtro: pais,
        fabricante_distribuidor_id: fabricante_distribuidor_id,
        producto_solicitud_id: producto_solicitud_id,
        fabricante_producto_solicitud_id: fabricante_producto_solicitud_id
    }
}
```

This should give you what you are looking for, which is for all of the ids to be passed into the url.

Comment: As you said I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: @ReynierPM That sounds like something unrelated to this issue (getting the query parameters). Might be better as a different question.

Comment: Yes but since the _original_ issue is not fixed yet, why should I open a new question? Better to answer here, no?

Comment: @ReynierPM Is the `data` function not filling in the url parameters still, or am I missing something from the original question? I only say it's probably better as a different question because _nothing that I changed_ calls/removes/adds a `length` property.